# powershell regex errors except warning from DBCC

Tags: sql-server, regex, powershell, regex-negation

I am trying to create powershell script that would go through a log file of some Sql Server script and investigate presence of word "error". I did that:

```
Get-Content $log | Select-String "error" -quiet  #returns true/false
```

or 
    Get-Content $log | Select-String "error" #returns lines with "error"

Problem is that my log file contains also warnings from DBCC like:

```
 26: DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error messages, contact your system administrator.
 24: DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error messages, contact your system administrator.
```

**How can I list just lines with "error" but without "If DBCC printed error messages"?**
I was trying things like:

```
Get-Content "d:\InsightMasterESF\logs\currentlog.txt" | Select-String -pattern "(error)(?!If DBCC printed error messages)"
```

But I do not know patterns for regex well.

Comment: The first rule of regex is "know your data".  If you need help with a regex, we need to know exactly what the data looks like that we need to match to.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `Where-Object` to filter out lines that match the text that you want to exclude.

```
Get-Content -Path $Log | Where-Object -FilterScript { $PSItem -match 'error' -and $PSItem -notmatch 'If DBCC printed'; };
```

Comment: I was going to give the same answer until you posted it. Might want to change the -notmatch 'DBCC' to be a little more specific though and make it -notmatch 'If DBCC printed' so that it doesn't exclude more than desired.

Answer (score 1):

Let me Know if this helps:

```
Select-String -Path "d:\InsightMasterESF\logs\currentlog.txt" -Pattern error | select-string -Pattern 'If DBCC printed error messages' -NotMatch -Quiet
```

-NotMatch Parameter takes care of not matching DBCC printed error message.